# How to add Seconds to existing Crystral report formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, rpt

I need help adding seconds to a time stamp on a crystal report RPT file.  The current formula is converting the time and stripping away seconds.  In CR, i can adjust the formatting to display "seconds" but they always show as 00 instead of the actual.  We have clients in multiple time zones but our server is set to Arizona.  If I adjust the formula to just **formula = CurrentDateTime**, it works but this affects our East Coast business partners as the report will show Arizona time for them.

```
formula  = CDateTime(CHTimeZoneCHDTTMConverterConvertDTTM ("CLIENT", Cstr(CurrentDateTime),{?ClientSTDTZ} ,{?ServerSTDTZ} ))
```

We're using Crystal Reports V. 14.0.2.36 RTM

Comment: Are you certain the `CHTimeZoneCHDTTMConverterConvertDTTM()` function you are using returns a date with a time stamp?  The `CStr(CurrentDateTime)` portion of your formula is definitely returning a Date Time Stamp, so the problem you are having is within the outer function that is doing the conversion for time zone.

You may want to look into the `ShiftDateTime()` function as an alternative.